# Is there a symbol to mean 'this is undefined'?

Tags: notation

Consider a partial function $f$ that is defined only for a few values of its domain (my exact use case is $\delta$ transition functions in automata). One can 'complete' it by saying $$g(x)=0\iff f(x) \text{ is not defined.}$$

Is there a symbol to mean "undefined"? Would it be correct, or accurate, to write $\nexists f(x)$?

Comment: Some people write $f(x)\uparrow$.

Comment: I remember $\bot$ being used. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Bottom_type.

Comment: However $\not\exists f(x)$ seems confusing though.

Comment: @Srivatsan You mean, $f(x) = \bot$? I remember something of the sort.

Comment: Ah yes. I meant $f(x) = \bot$. (But this is just what I remember, so not to be trusted. Hopefully some expert can corroborate.)

Comment: In matrix algebra texts, $\perp$ is usually reserved for the annihilator of a matrix i.e. $(A^\perp)^T A = 0 $ and $\begin{bmatrix} A &A^\perp \end{bmatrix}$ is full rank.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[A language for mathematical knowledge management](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1386) uses $f(x)\uparrow$.

Comment: I had not seen this before, but I have seen $f(x) \downarrow$ to mean that $f(x)$ *is* defined, so this makes sense.

Comment: The link you provided is dead :(

Comment: @exhuma I replaced it with a more stable link.

Comment: I think you will loose more readers using this symbol rather than not using it and writing in plain text. From what I have seen on this site purely logical symbols are not commonly used except in this field (logic) and the large majority of people replace them by plain text (and/or for instance are almost never replaced by $\land,\lor$ in general math).

Answer (score 0):

Thus, $f(x)\uparrow$ and $f(x)=\bot$ were suggested, although the prior use of the latter is perhaps not common (I did not quickly find it from Google).

$f(x)=\frac00$ might suit some contexts.

I would use none of the above without defining it first.