# How to denote "undefined" as a predicate?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

Let $P \subset \mathbb{N}$ be a finite index set and suppose that there is a *partial function* $f:P \to P$, which is undefined for some strict subset of $P$.

Then, suppose I have a function $g: P \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ defined as
$$
g(i) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & f(i) \text{ is undefined} \\
1 & f(i) \text{ is defined.}
\end{cases}
$$

What is the formally correct way to denote these predicates?
Could $\not \exists f(i)$ and $\exists f(i)$ work?

Comment: In the context of recursion theory, I have seen $f(x)\!\downarrow$ used to mean that $f(x)$ is defined and $f(x)\!\uparrow$ to mean that $f(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: $\exists p(i)$ doesn't look right. If these are functions represented as sets of pairs in set theory, then  "$p(i)$ is defined" just means $i \in \mbox{dom}(p)$ (and your function $g$ is just the characteristic function $\chi_{\mbox{dom}(p)}$). In other contexts, a modality (like $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ in Clive Newstead's comment) might be more appropriate (there are many logics for working with  undefined terms). (PS. there is some mix-up between $f$ and $p$ in the question.)

Comment: PPS: I see that an answer proposing $i \in \mbox{dom}(p)$ was posted but later deleted. That answer was perfectly good in the context of the usual representation of functions in set theory. When one writes that $f$ is a partial function from $X$ to $Y$, it is not possible to recover $X$ or $Y$ from the representation of $P$. In making a category out of sets and partial functions, one has to represent the functions as triples $(X, f, Y)$.

Comment: Another way to represent partial functions $f : P \to P$ would be in terms of a "full" function $f_{full} : P \to P \sqcup \{ undef \}$; in this representation, you would simply test whether $f_{full}(i) = undef$ or not.

Comment: @RobArthan, the mix-up has been amended. Is there a reason $\exists f(i)$ would not work? Would $\text{dom}(f)$ automatically convey the *domain of definition*, rather than $P$?

Comment: In addition to the cited duplicate question, see [Is there any symbol for "undefined"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1127115)