# What is the symbol for undefined?

Tags: notation, terminology, definition

Just how there is a symbol for no real solutions (the empty set) and there is DNE for does not exist, what symbol or abbreviation would you use for undefined?

Comment: According to [Math - Symbol for Undefined](http://www.solving-math-problems.com/math-symbol-for-undefined.html), dividing a number by $0$ may be represented by UNDEF, but the staff are unaware of any specific symbol meaning "undefined".  For what it's worth, I also am unaware of any such symbol, at least anything which is generally accepted by the math community.

Comment: [Not so fast](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), @JohnOmielan; sometimes it is possible to divide by $0$.

Comment: I have seen a handful of authors simply write "undefined" where necessary.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for pointing out about wheel theory.  I believe the staff at the Web site meant that in within the real/complex number field, dividing any non-$0$ value by $0$ is usually considered to be undefined,  while $0$ divided by $0$ is often called indeterminate. However, in addition to wheel theory, there may be other math systems where division by $0$ is defined and consistent with those particular set of axioms and conditions.  The important thing with terms and definitions is that it's explicitly specified, or at least quite clear, what they're referring to.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61914/265466 and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics).